# GitHub Actions: How to view inputs for workflow_dispatch?

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

My idea here is to write my inputs from workflow_dispatch on each pipeline run. [image: ![enter image description here].

For example, in Bitbucket pipelines input parameters shown after **custom** - [image]

Is there a way to do something similar for GitHub?

Comment: Would the [new `inputs` context for `workflow_dispatch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72576146/6309) help you access those values?

Answer (score 16):

Although this does not directly answer your question, I'm adding it here because this is where I landed looking for the answer on how to output all my workflow inputs.

In my case I am using a `workflow_dispatch` trigger - YMMV if you are using a different trigger, but I suspect it would work the same way.

As with the other answer proposed, you will need to do this as a `step` within your job:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      myInput:
        default: "my input value"
jobs:
  myJob:
    steps:
      - name: Output Inputs
        run: echo "${{ toJSON(github.event.inputs) }}"
```

This will result in output you can view in your GitHub action execution output with the inputs serialized as JSON:

```json
{
  "myInput": "my input value"
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`run-name` parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-of-run-name) to change the name of the run in the actions list:

> #### Example of `run-name`
>
> ```yaml
> run-name: Deploy to ${{ inputs.deploy_target }} by @${{ github.actor }}
> ```

Be aware that, if you are using Github Enterprise server, this parameter was introduced in version 3.8.

Comment: Holy moly, I've been looking for this for over a year! I had just resigned myself to it not being possible without direct API access

Answer (score 8):

If you have only a few simple input values (from `workflow_dispatch`) then you can include them in the name of the job:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      my_value:
        description: 'My input value'
        required: true
        default: 'foo'
        type: string

jobs:
  my_job:
    name: "My job [my_value: ${{ github.event.inputs.my_value }}]"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    ....
```

This way you will be able to see the input directly in the GitHub UI.

Comment: In lieu of them allowing the actual name to be changed this has been a life saver. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really alter how they will be displayed on the list I'm afraid.

All you can do is to log your input variables inside action itself, like this:

```
jobs:
  debugInputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo "Var1: ${{ github.event.inputs.var1 }}"
        echo "Var2: ${{ github.event.inputs.var2 }}"
```

If you want to see them in summary, you can use a [notice](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-a-notice-message) or [warning](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-a-warning-message) message mark:

Comment: Well this is quite the oversight on the part of the github team.  The setup job node should most definitely include any input variables used, otherwise there is no way to really prove what values were used for a given job.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar and landed on logging + writing to the [Job Summary](https://github.blog/2022-05-09-supercharging-github-actions-with-job-summaries/).

I created [a small action that can easily be used as a first step in your workflow](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/actions/tree/main/gh-context), since I found myself need

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to set the `run-name` of the workflow and parse that for `workflow_dispatch` inputs.

But, if you want to retrieve the `workflow_dispatch` objects for workflows that have already been ran, the data is only available in the logs.

Admittedly a little hacky, but this script does just that (loops through a list of workflow runs, downloads/extracts logs, and uses `sed` to extract the inputs): https://github.com/joshjohanning/github-misc-scripts/blob/main/gh-cli/get-workflow-dispatch-inputs.sh

This will return something such as:

```json
[
  {
    "workflowName": "workflow-b",
    "workflowId": "5870059990",
    "inputs": {
      "animal": "bee",
      "color": "orange",
      "food": "avocado"
    },
    "createdAt": "2023-08-15T17:45:21Z",
    "conclusion": "success"
  }
],
```