# How to replace a cron in a shell script using sed?

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I need to replace a cron entry in a file using sed or awk.

tried this : didnt work

```
sed -i 's/0 0 * * 0/0 1 * * 1/g' script.sh
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p .github/workflows

cd .github/workflows
touch semgrep.yml

cat << EOF > semgrep.yml
name: Semgrep
on:
  pull_request: {}
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/semgrep.yml
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * 0'
jobs:
  semgrep:
    name: Static Analysis Scan
    runs-on: ubuntu-18-04
```

Kindly help me with the same .

Comment: `sed -i '/cron:/s/0 0 \* \* 0/0 1 * * 1/'` script.sh

Comment: BTW, is there a reason why you don't use a text editor for this task?

Comment: I am executing a script which has this cron and that has to be replaced

Comment: It might be possible, in certain cases to use regular expressions to parse yaml files, but such as xml, jq and a like, yaml files are formatted according to a standard. Such files are better processed with tools that understand this format. For yaml files, it might be best to make use of `yq`

Comment: Note: I have [edited my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72576146/6309) about "GitHub action how to access the inputs", in order to address your comment "Is it possible to avoid printing the inputs in the logs?"

Answer (score 2):

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) to edit the file in place (`-i`):

```bash
yq -i '.on.schedule[].cron = "0 1 * * 1"' semgrep.yml
```

would turn a `semgrep.yml` containing

```yaml
name: Semgrep
on:
  pull_request: {}
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/semgrep.yml
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * 0'
jobs:
  semgrep:
    name: Static Analysis Scan
    runs-on: ubuntu-18-04
```

into one containing

```yaml
name: Semgrep
on:
  pull_request: {}
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/semgrep.yml
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 1 * * 1'
jobs:
  semgrep:
    name: Static Analysis Scan
    runs-on: ubuntu-18-04
```

Comment: I wanted to modify it my shell script and not the yaml file. Can you help me with the same.

Comment: @arunkumar `yq` is a tool to query and manipulate `yaml` files, just as `sed` is for text files. Having either one of them work on a mixed file is widely discouraged as it is highly error-prone because none of the tools can do the job of the other but in a mixed file you would need the expertise of both. Therefore, I guess the best way in your case would be to modify a separate `yaml` file (which may be based on but distinct from your `semgrep.yml`, temporary even) using `yq`, and integrate that into your shell script (using `cat` or `sed` if necessary).